# CakePHP htaccess redirecting to live site when running site locally

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I am working on a website which is using CakePHP.  I need to start adding some features to this site so i pulled everything from the live site to my development machine(mac os lion with MAMP server).  When i try to load up the site (localhost/example.com/), it automatically redirects me to the live site(www.example.com).

Here is the root htaccess file contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

When i comment out the **first two** `RewriteCond` and **first** `RewriteRule`, my machine throws a 500 internal server error with no apache/php log output.

How can i run this website locally without automatically redirecting to the live site?

Is there any additional information i could provide?

edit: here is my document_root: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`.  shouldn't it be `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.com`?
edit: here is the `/webroot/.htaccess` file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule img/([0-9]*x[0-9]*)/(.*)/(.*)$ files/image/$2/$1/$3 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule (js|css)/vendors/(.*)$ vendors.php?type=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType text/css .css

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # compress content with type html, text, and css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript text/js

  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  # Don't compress images/flash 
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
  \.(?:swf|flv)$ no-gzip dont-vary

  # Don't compress images
  # SetEnvIfNoCase          Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  # SetEnvIfNoCase          Request_URI \/image\.php no-gzip dont-vary

  # Also don't compress PDF and Flash-files 17-01-2004 MM
  SetEnvIfNoCase          Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # properly handle requests coming from behind proxies
    Header append Vary User-Agent
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
  ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 10 years"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 10 years"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 years"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 years"
  ExpiresByType video/x-flv "access plus 10 years"
</IfModule>

FileETag none
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>
# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
# 1 MIN
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

edit: i've enabled debug logging level for apache so i can see more log messages.  here is the log details upon visiting the root of the project with an error 500:

`[Fri Jun 01 11:00:35 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client ::1] Zlib: Compressed 0 to 2 : URL /example.com/webroot/index.php`

`[Fri Jun 01 11:00:35 2012] [debug] mod_headers.c(756): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()`

I've also included the access_log data after visiting the site with error 500:

`127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2012:11:03:02 -0400] "GET /example.com/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.53 Safari/536.5"`

Comment: verify apache rewrite module is enable ?

Comment: i'm confident that the rewrite module is enabled. (phpinfo() shows loaded modules including mod_rewrite).  i also run other websites locally using rewrite that work fine(zend framework based)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing .htaccess code with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /example.com/

    RewriteRule (?!^webroot/)^(.*)$ webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: upon replacing my code with yours, i get this error: `The requested URL /webroot/ was not found on this server.`  my project def. contains the `webroot` directory and it is at the root of my project.

Comment: Just to test, rename above .htaccess to something else and then try loading `http://site.com/webroot/` does it open? Also do you have another .htaccess in webroot by any chance?

Comment: Also would like to know what is your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Comment: there is an htaccess in webroot. i've updated my question to include more info.  also you menioned going to `http://site.com/webroot/`. did you mean to have me visit the live site? upon doing this(on the live site), the page loads normally but shows a page not found message.  visiting `localhost/site.com/webroot` results in 500 internal server error

Comment: Thanks for the updates can you also provide your *exact* directory structure like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839562/mod-rewrite-i-cant-make-it-to-work-like-i-want. I have difficulty to understand where the webroot folder actually is. Is it directly under $DOCUMENT_ROOT or not.

Comment: `webroot` for this project is under `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.com/`.  so it looks like this: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.com/webroot/`

Comment: Thanks, good to know that. I believe you have my suggested .htaccess in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.com` and there is no .htaccess in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` is that right?

Comment: this is correct - there is no htaccess in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`

Comment: Alright I edited my answer. This will go in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.com/.htaccess` file. Also if you still get 500 error please report log message from error.log file.

Comment: i've updated the htaccess and i get a 500.  there is no updated log output for apache or php(`/Applications/MAMP/logs/`) after encountering this 500

Comment: Every time Apache encounters an error there is a log entry in the error.log file. Pls check `/Applications/MAMP/logs/` directory.

Comment: So what URL are you using to test this? And it still isn't writing actual error (the reason) behind 500.

Comment: i'm always using my local URL: `http://localhost/example.com` or `http://localhost/example.com/webroot` like you suggested i do once

Comment: But you also wrote that when you commented my suggested `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.com/.htaccess` you are still getting 500 error which means actual error is in your existing .htaccess code. Moreover I cannot get to see the actual error so its kind of difficult for me to guess the actual error in your existing .htaccess code.