# mod_rewrite - I can't make it to work like I want

Tags: php, model-view-controller, .htaccess, apache2

Thanks for reading. First of all, I got one .htaccess inside my root directory with the following statement :

```
# Mod Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule     ^$              /root/              [L]
    RewriteRule     (.*)            /root/$1            [L]
</IfModule>
```

and inside root folder I got this file :

```
# Mod Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /root/index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, in the folder `/root`, I got three folders : `css`, `js` and `images`.

My application is designed to be separated from my MVC framework (a bit like CodeGgniter is). So here's the tree :

```
- application
    - my application files are there
- root
    - css
    - js
    - images
- grecko
    - my mvc framework files are there
```

Like this, I can update my framework without touching the entire website who run under the application folder.

Anyway, what I would like to do now is to move the three folder I said above ( `css`, `js` and `images`) and move them inside `/application/assets/`. But since everything is redirected to `/root/`, I will need a rule that allow request like that `http://www.domain.tld/css/blabla.css` to be mapped to `/application/assets/css/blabla.css`, etc.

I did try but without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)(/.*|)$ application/assets/$1$2 [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
    RewriteRule ^ root${REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Perfectly working ! But since you wrote it too fast hehe, there was a mistake so I ended with those line : `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200` and `RewriteRule (.*) root/$1 [L]`

Comment: Good to know that it's working for you. `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200` is actually making sure that internal redirect is applied only once. What was happening for you that both rules were being applied one after another. As you can see in the RewriteLog you provided that: `rewrite 'application/assets/css/global.css' -> 'root/application/assets/css/global.css'` is happening which is sending everyhing to root/

Comment: Forgot to add that `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` is an internal variable used by mod_rewrite module and it is set to 200 after first successful internal redirect.

Comment: Ok, thanks you ! I knew what was for but didn't know the reason to apply here... it's a npretty nice trick. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the .htaccess of your web root (not root folder):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)(.*) application/assets/$1$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application/assets [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) root/$1 [L]
```

Avoid extraneous spaces.

Comment: Doesn't work. It does nothing. I even tryed inside my root folder. He sent it to /root/index.php/$1 and he think `css`, `image` or `js` are controller so it clearly don't work. Thanks !

Comment: This should be caught before it goes to root or root/index.php - can you post the full file?

Comment: All you see above is the full .htaccess file. I know it's weird, like I said I did try but I couldn't make it work since it does "nothing" as it my MVC think I want CSS controller, or images by example.

Comment: I mean post the full file after you added my rules.

Comment: Is there another .htaccess in `/application`? Can you add some RewriteLog rules to the VirtualHost config?

Comment: No, the only .htaccess who exist are above so one in the root and one in root named folder. Here you go : http://pastebin.com/7VjwVKfn

Comment: Found the bug - added a RewriteCond to fix it. Check now.

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work either... anubhava's solution is working.

Comment: Yes that's a neater way to do it - just avoid internal redirects. I wonder why mine isn't working though. Update the logs?

Comment: Ah found the bug in mine. I was missing a slash.